# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/octet-stream

Tags: google-visualization

Using the following code to save a Google chart. But it is getting downloaded as a file and not an image, it was throwing following

```
"Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/octet-stream: "data:image/octet-stream;base64,..."
```

And the code:

```
function getImgData(chartContainer) {
    var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('div')[1];
    var svg = chartArea.innerHTML;
    var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
    var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', chartArea.offsetWidth);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', chartArea.offsetHeight);


    canvas.setAttribute(
        'style',
        'position: absolute; ' +
        'top: ' + (-chartArea.offsetHeight * 2) + 'px;' +
        'left: ' + (-chartArea.offsetWidth * 2) + 'px;');
    doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvg(canvas, svg);
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
    return imgData;
  }

  function saveAsImg(chartContainer) {
    var imgData = getImgData(chartContainer);
    window.location = imgData.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
  }
```

Comment: what type of chart are you saving? why not use [`getImageURI()`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing)? also, can you clarify, _getting downloaded as a file and not an image_? how do you plan to save the chart, if not in a file?

Comment: It was a file without an extension. Something like a windows exe file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an anchor tag with a `download` attribute to assign the file name

and most charts have a `getImageURI` method

also, don't see the need to `replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream")`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      // set anchor tag
      var saveLink = document.getElementById('saveLink');
      saveLink.href = chart.getImageURI();

      // cause download to occur
      saveLink.click();
    });

    chart.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours'],
      ['A', 19.2],
      ['B', 30.8],
      ['C', 50.0]
    ]), {
      height: 200,
      chartArea: {
        top: 24
      },
      legend: 'none',
      pieHole: 0.4,
      theme: 'maximized',
      width: 200
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<a id="saveLink" download="chart.png">Save Chart</a>
```